# Wifi is working on android 4.2.2 , but not on 6, exclamation mark in status bar

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop, 6.0-marshmallow

I'm trying to connect to a wifi network using 4 phones.

1 phone uses Android 4.2.2, and the others are using Android 6 and 5.0.1.

The one with the Android 4.2.2, everything's work fine.

On the others, I get an exclamation mark next to the WiFi icon on the status bar, and no communication.

Are there any WiFi restrictions between Android 4.2.2 and Android 5.0.1, 6?

Answer (score 0):

- Check the 5.1/6.0 phones to see if static IP is set up on them by long-pressing on the network, and selecting modify network. It will look like this: (except you're on 5.1 & 6.0)
  [image: static ip]
- Turn off WEP/WPA on your router and see if it solves the problem
- If it does, set up a new WPA2 Personal with AES (not TKIP!) for maximum compatibility.
- Turn off WPS (Wifi Protected Setup) on your router. (It's hardly a security feature more of an annoyance. It just exposes the location of the router because everyone has to click the button to connect.)
- Check your DHCP settings to make sure nothing looks foul.

That is all I can think of. Hope one of them does the trick!